# Calculating change in entropy, Integration help?

Tags: integration, entropy

So I need to calculate the change in entropy for a non-ideal gas over two states.
The equation im looking at using is

$$T\,ds = dh - v\,dP \text{ or } T\,ds = du + P\,dv$$

where $h=u+Pv$ , $s = \text{entropy}$, $P = \text{pressure}$, $ du = C_v\,dT$

Im just struggling on how to integrate this between two states 1 and state 2.Do i integrate first or substitute values in first.

First i would rearrange the equation to..

$$ds = \frac {dh} T - \frac{v\,dP} T$$

The integration bit im stuck on.

Any help on how to integrate this equation with respect to state 1 and 2 would be great thanks :)